# Limit of $\exp(z)$ as $z\to \infty$ for specific domains

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

Using this

> **Definition:** Let $f:D \to \mathbb C$ be a single-valued complex
> function, and suppose that $\infty$ is an accumulation point of $D$.
> The point $\infty$ is said to be the *limit of $f(z)$ as $z$ approaches*
> $\infty$ if for every $K>0$ there is an $M>0$ (depending of $K$) such
> that $$ |f(z)|>K \;\text{ whenever }\; |z|>M \;\text{ and }\; z\in D. $$

I am trying to undestand the following:

**Example:** *For $f(z)=e^z$, $D = \{z~|~\text{Re}(z)>0\}$, we have $\lim_{z\to \infty}f(z) = \infty.$*

Using the above definition, for any given $K>0$ we have that
$$|f(z)|=|e^z| = e^x>K$$
whenever $x>\ln K$.

1. In this case, will it be enough to take $M> \max\{0, \ln K\}$ to have $\lim_{z\to \infty}f(z) = \infty$? Is this a valid argument?
2. What is special about $D = \{z~|~\text{Re}(z)>0\}$?
3. Why if I consider $e^z$ defined on $D_1 = \{z~|~\text{Re}(z)=0\}$ then there is no limit?
4. Why if I consider $e^z$ defined on $D_2 = \{z~|~\text{Re}(z)<0\}$ then $\lim_{z\to \infty}f(z) = 0$?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you need narrower domains; for example the angle $D=|\arg z| \le \delta <\pi/2$ gives you indeed $|f(z)| \to \infty, |z| \to \infty, z \in D$ since then you have that $\Re z \ge |z|\cos \delta, z \in D$ so $|e^z|=e^{\Re z} \ge e^{|z|\cos \delta} \to \infty$; similarly if you do $\pi/2+\delta \le |\arg z| \le \pi, 0<\delta < \pi/2$ you get an angle domain where $e^z \to 0, z \to \infty$

Comment: Ok, so for my restrictions mentioned above, I need to consider also the argument, like in your examples. What about the case $\text{Re}(z)=0$? Is that the only correct case? Does this argument work for the domain $D=|\arg (z-2)|\leq \delta \lt \pi/2$? In this domain also $f(z)\to \infty$ as $z\to \infty$?

Comment: Where $\Re z=0$ we have that $e^z$ oscillates with modulus $1$ so is bounded; yes $|\arg(z-2)| \le \delta<\pi/2$ works

Comment: More generally any angle $|\arg(z-z_0)| \le \delta<\pi/2$ for any complex number $z_0$ is good since $\Re (z-z_0)\ge |z-z_0|\cos \delta$ so $\Re z \to \infty$ when $|z| \to \infty$

Comment: Hi Conrad, after thinking for a long time, I think that it should be $Im(z)\leq \delta < \pi/2$ instead of $arg(z)\leq \delta < \pi/2$. This is to avoid approaching $\infty$ through a path parallel to the imaginary axis. But I might be wrong. What do you think?

Comment: When you are in an angle as above any vertical line exits from it if the absolute value is big; your domain doesn't work unless you bound the imaginary part below and the real part below too and then it's a half strip which is included in an an angle as above, so it's less general (on vertical lines the argument goes to zero at infinity so the can condition we have precludes that which proves that any vertical line has only a finite segment contained in an angle as described)

Answer (score 1):

$f(z) \to \infty$ as $|z| \to \infty$ is **false** in all cases includubg the first one. Consider a fixed $x$. $|f(x+in)|=|e^{x+in}|=e^{x}$ and $|x+in| \to \infty$ as $ n \to \infty$. Since $x$ may be $0$, positive or negative it follows that $f(z) \to \infty$ as $|z| \to \infty$ is false in all cases.